# Expand and shorten file path of current cmd

Tags: cmd, windows-xp

I'm unable to find anything regarding this on the net. E.g., When I'm in `C:\PROGRA~1>` I would like to expand it to `C:\Program Files>`. Also I would like to change other way around, when I'm in `C:\Program Files>` to short it to `C:\PROGRA~1>`. Note that I'm talking about cmd and when I'm in cmd and going through file and folders, not in batch file.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.  Also, when you say "I'm talking about cmd... not in batch file", that says this question is probably better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: If you don't want a batch file solution, than don't add batch-file as a tag. And given that constraint, rojo is correct, this question belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: Are you cd'ing to "C:\PROGRA~1" or to "C:\Program Files" when you first enter the directory?

Comment: I guess putting batch tag was wrong. I don't want to change directory or list files in it. I just want to change way how is current path showed. Changing `C:\PROGRA~1>` to `C:\Program Files>` and back, nothing more.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question. If one can use powershell, the answer is with Get-Item, for example... (Get-Item 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2').FullName

Answer (score 2):

Closest thing I can think of is

```js
cd "\Program Files"
for %I in (.) do @echo %~sI
```

to show the current directory in short name format.  I don't think there's a native cmd-interpreter way to expand a short path name, but you can abuse PowerShell from the cmd console.

```js
cd \PROGRA~1
powershell "(pwd).path"
```

To get a directory listing containing short directory names, use `dir /X`

Comment: Nice trick with the powershell. It's hard to get the full/long path with pure batch but its possible.Check dbenham's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654988/get-full-path-and-long-file-name-from-short-file-name)

Answer (score 1):

There is not any native command with the indicated behaviour.

The prompt shows the current path depending on how the current active directory has been reached. Changing to the short representation is an easy task (you only need a `for` command to retrieve the short name), but changing to the long representation needs a full path with every folder in the path in its long form.

You can include a batch file somewhere in your path (for easier calling) to handle the task. Something like (changes `short <-> long` when called)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem check if short and long references to current directory do not match
    for /d %%x in (".") do if /i not "%%~sx"=="%%~fx" (
        endlocal 
        echo Changing to short path 
        cd "%%~sx"
        goto :eof
    ) else (
        rem Retrieve current active directory information for later use
        set "fullPath=%%~dx"
        set "folders=%%~fx"
    )

    rem Prepare to enumerate folders from top to bottom.
    rem For each of the levels, we will use a wildcard on the short name.
    rem The wildcard expansion will retrieve the long name of this level.
    rem The rest is just folder names concatenation and delayed expansion
    rem enable/disable to avoid problems with folders containing 
    rem "!" in their names.

    set "folders=%folders:*\=%"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%a in ("!folders:\=" "!") do for %%f in ("!fullPath!") do (
        endlocal
        rem Use a wildcard to search a folder matching the current level
        for /d %%c in ("%%~f\%%~a?") do if /i "%%~snxc"=="%%~a" (
            rem Matching folder found. Save its long name
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for %%d in ("!fullPath!") do (
                endlocal
                set "fullPath=%%~d\%%~nxc"
            )
        )
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    )
    endlocal

    rem Search done. Check if a directory change is needed
    for /d %%a in (".") do for /d %%b in ("%fullPath%") do if not "%%~fa"=="%%~fb" (
        endlocal
        echo Changing to long path 
        cd "%fullPath%"
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not fully understand your question. If you would like to control the way path appears in `cmd`, one of the options is to use `prompt`. For example, in case you would like to hide the entire path and instead you want only `>` to appear, you can do the following

`prompt $g`

The result is

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\XXXXX>prompt $g
>
```

To show the path of the current folder, you use `prompt $n`. For all options, you can print out the list as `prompt /?`