# VBA Dos.Path to Win.Path

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script which lists all files in a location recursively.
Due to the string limit I have to used the `Object.ShortPath` as the location to avoid the path being to long.

In the Excel list I need the normal path as it later on has to become searchable in a database.

Is there a way to get the normal `win path` with the `dos path`?

Edit:
The Ultimate Goal is indexing every file (not the file itself but its properties)  in  elasticsearch and building a webapp to search quickly for any file by name, location, dates, owner etc.

without the ShortPath I lose a couple of files which are buried in subfolders.

yet I need the normal path of each file to tokenize substrings for the query.

Right now I'm cycling through each file with VBA and writing `.path .size .type .name` of the FSO in an Excel sheet which then gets "saved" to JSON.

for now the number of files are approximately 500k with potential scaling to XX million.

That's why I can't change the location of the files.

Comment: You will need to explain a bit further, and add the code you are using. Does your script make use of the DIR function? Why is the filename too long, is it the filename itself, or the location of the folder? If the latter, why not place the folder right under C:/ to shorten the filepath?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654988/get-full-path-and-long-file-name-from-short-file-name has a vbscript solution which could easily be ported to VBA

Comment: I switched to python. In my case twice as fast and no limitations in path-length